# WSO2: using a property to save the current message

Tags: wso2

I'm a WSO2 newbie, so sorry in advance if my answer seems a stupid one ...

In a sequence I've the following code ....

```
<property name="InitialMessage" expression="$body" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
<log level="full">
    <property name="INITIAL MESSAGE" expression="get-property('InitialMessage')"/>
</log>
```

In the server logs I've the following ...

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-07-04 11:27:46,569]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: process, SOAPAction: process, MessageID: urn:uuid:0D6752DAEC5AA438C92484199554844771301894479, Direction: request, **INITIAL MESSAGE = null**,..............
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance .. .

Cesare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please never think that your questions are stupid ones :). I think `scope` value that you have defined in the property mediator is invalid. Scoped must be `default`. It means you do not want to configure it and please tryout by removing it  You can find detail about using `$body`  from WSO2 ESB [doc](http://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-%24body)